# model item pased into the dictionary is of type PagdList[TimeRepoLib.Usr] but this dictionary requires model item of type TimeReprtViewMod

Tags: c#, asp.net, list

What I have to pass to my view in controller? This is my View where I represent my controller:

```
@model TimeReportingWebApp.TimeReportViewMod
@using PagedList.Mvc;
<link href="~/Content/PagedList.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Users";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Users", FormMethod.Get))
{
    <p>
        Find by name: @Html.TextBox("SearchString", ViewBag.CurrentFilter as string) 
        <input type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary" value="Search" />
    </p>
}
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.ActionLink(Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Model1.Select(x => x.Login)).ToHtmlString(), "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.NameSortParm, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
        </th>
        <th>
    </tr>
```

And here is my Controller where I want to return both modules :

```
public ActionResult Index(string sortOrder, string currentFilter, string searchString,  int? page)
        {
            ViewBag.CurrentSort = sortOrder;
            ViewBag.NameSortParm = String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sortOrder) ? "login_desc" : "";

            var users = from s in db.Users.Include(u => u.CustomerProject).Include(u => u.Service).Include(u => u.Customer) select s;
            //var sortUsers = from s in db.Users select s;

            if(searchString != null)
            {
                page = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                searchString = currentFilter;
            }

            ViewBag.CurrentFilter = searchString;

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            {
                users = users.Where(s => s.Login.Contains(searchString) || s.UserName.Contains(searchString));
            }

            switch (sortOrder)
            {
                case "login_desc":
                    users = users.OrderByDescending(s => s.Login);
                    break;
                default:
                    users = users.OrderBy(s => s.Login);
                    break;
            }

            int pageSize = 3;
            int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
            return View(users.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
```

My module class with definitions:

```
namespace TimeReportingWebApp
{
    public class TimeReportViewMod
    {
        public IEnumerable<TimeReportingLib.User> Model1 { get; set; }
        public IPagedList<TimeReportingLib.User> Model2 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

What can I change in my controller? I tryed to change my @module List or IEnumerable , but it doesn't work.

Eddit: I think I need to change something here:

```
return View(users.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
```

Because View and controller should be the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is telling you exactly whats going on, in your view you are expecting

```
@model TimeReportingWebApp.TimeReportViewMod <----- TimeReportViewMod
```

And in your Controller you are returning

```
PagdList[timeReportLib.user]
```

in order to make it work, you must change the model for the view to **PagdList[timeReportLib.user]** or change the returning value from the controller to  **TimeReportingWebApp.TimeReportViewMod**